# 301 redirect non-www in subfolder via .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect all non-www pages to a www page on my site using the .htaccess file. It's a multilingual site and it's set up with a site in the root folder in danish, and an English version in www.domain.com/en/.

I got the non-www redirect working on the danish part but I'm having problems in the english subfolder. Each folder has it's own .htaccess.

On the danish end my request looks like this:

```
#301 redirect #RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301]
```

And I'm thinking that the English equivalent should look like this:

```
#RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com/en/$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.example.com/en/$1 [R=301]
```

I would really appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't include the path as part of the `%{HTTP_HOST}` variable, which **only contains the hostname**. Thus, `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com/en/$` will **always** be false.

You can match the path as part of the regex in the rewrite rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule ^en/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/en/$1 [R=301]
```

But this doesn't make any sense. If you're placing these rules in the `/en/` folder, then you don't need to check for the `/en/` *at all*:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/en/$1 [R=301]
```

Since the rules won't get processed if you aren't already requesting something that starts with `/en/`

Comment: Ahh.. That makes alot of sense now.. Thanks for the reply! :)